# Commerce Pricing Rules Not Applying During Checkout

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

I have a pricing rule that's defined essentially along the lines of the one [described here](https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/sell-price-calculation), and it appears correctly when I add items to the cart. But as soon as I progress to the check out the prices all revert to their base price not the discounted price.

With the Rules debugging enabled all the rules appear to fire, but the calculation doesn't appear to be saved correctly. Since there aren't a lot of hits in Google for this (or at least for the various search terms I can think of) I presume we're doing something odd that's causing trouble, but I've slowly removed every complexity I can so I'm as close to the user guide example as I can all without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the [Rules 2.8 regression resolved by Commerce 1.11.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2408705)